# where is the exit function of a MFC application?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

i can't seem to find any exit function in my mfc application codes.
i want my application to actually save some settings when i click on the red cross on the top right of the application. anyone knows where is this exit function located at? thanks

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what type of application it is. Check `CWinApp::ExitInstance` which will be called always. You may also look into `CDialog::OnCancel`, `CWnd::OnClose`, `CWnd::OnDestroy`, `CFrameWnd::OnNcDestroy`

Comment: WM_CLOSE (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/ms632617(VS.85).aspx) is the windows message that is sent by Windows to indicate that the window is requested to be closed. Depending on the type of the window one of the above listed methods will be called. If you are doing plain Win32 C programming, then see here for an example on how to handle WM_CLOSE (http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html).

Comment: WM_CLOSE is sent before WM_DESTROY - For dialogs, it would call OnCancel.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a dialog based application, I prefer the following code

```
void CMFC_dialogDlg::OnOK()
{
}

void CMFC_dialogDlg::OnCancel()
{

}

void CMFC_dialogDlg::OnClose()
{
  //Call Save Function
  CDialog::OnOK();
}
```

After adding the following code i will remove the Ok and Cancel button from the dialog so that i will prevent the application from closing while pressing Esc/Enter key.